# Is it possible the division polynomials evaluated at fixed point to be perfect powers unbounded number of times?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be elliptic curve over the rationals and $P=(X_P,Y_P)$ point on $E$.

$\psi_n$ are the division polynomials.

Define $a_n=\psi_n(X_P,Y_P)$.

> Is it possible $a_n$ to be perfect power unbounded number of times?

Tried to solve this with many scaled integral points, but couldn't.

The related question about $Z_n$, the square root of the denominator of 
$x$-coordinate is positive via scaling many rational points to integral.

Comment: Do you assume $E/\mathbb{Q}$ ? Do you assume $P$ to have integer coordinates in a given Weierstrass equation ? Do you assume that $P$ has good reduction at all primes ?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I only assume $E/\mathbb{Q}$ and nothing about $P$.

Comment: So $a_n$ is a rational number.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich yes, it is rational. Though in special cases it might be integer.

Comment: For a given $(E,P)$ it will only finitely many times give an integer, I would think. Why are you interested in this question ? It seems hard that one can say anything interesting about it other than that it is very unlikely that there could be infinitely many perfect powers in any such sequence.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I think for $P=(0,0)$ of infinite order it is _always_ integer. Check the Shipsey reference here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich From the above reference on p.40 of the pdf you can easily construct $b_n= k^{n^2-1}a_n$ for all $k$. In particular you can make unbounded $a_n$ squareful.

Comment: Sure, sorry, if $x(P)$ and $y(P)$ are integers and the equation has integer coefficients then $a_n$ is an integer. - Non-square-free, yes, that is very easy, but perfect squares or even perfect powers are hard. But why do you want them perfect powers ?